# Click on a label to display texbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm trying to have a label on top of a page which users can click which will hide the label and textbox will appear. However, I can't get it to work.

Razor code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "Name" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new {htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control", id = "NameTextBox"}})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { id = "NameTexBoxValidator" })
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#Name").click(function setCompleteStatus() {
    if ($("#Name").is(":visible")) {
        $("#NameTextBox").hide();
    } else {
        $("#Name").show();
    }
});
```

Comment: You have given all 3 elements the same `id` attribute (which is invalid html). And you don't have any `<label>` elements - are you referring to the text generated by `@Html.DisplayFor()`?

Comment: @Regent, Your right, although who knows if that's a typo. In any case there is no element with `id="Name"`

Comment: That was a typo, sorry. I already changed it on my question.

Comment: You still have invalid html (2 elements with `id="NameTextBox")`, but inspect the html your generating. `@Html.DisplayFor()` does not create a html element - its just a string - there is no element with `id="Name"`

Comment: @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { id = "NameTexBox" }) change the id of this, lets just say "NameTexBoxValidator"

Comment: Exactly - there is **no** element with `id="Name"` !

Comment: @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name, new `{ id = "Name" }`)

Comment: As I have already stated, that does NOT generate a html element! What are you actually trying to do here? Why would you have such an awful user interface. If the form is for editing, use `TextBoxFor()`, if its for display only, use `DisplayFor()`

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, have a label (title) which user can click on to edit which will bring up the textbox and clicking the enter button brings back the label with the text from the textbox.

Comment: The question is why would you do that. Good web UI's have been developed over decades and this is not one of those

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed  `@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name, new { id = "Name" })`
to `@Html.Label(Model.Name, new { id = "Name" })` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear the code but i can give it a try, this code will hide the label onclick and show the textBox as you asked.

```js
$("#Name").click(function() {
    if ($("#Name").is(":visible")) {
      $("#NameTextBox").show();
      $("#Name").hide();
    }
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <label id="Name" for="male">Male</label>
  <input id="NameTextBox" type="text" style="display:none;">
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, you snippet works... however, it doesn't work in my case (using razor)... I'm guessing it's something to do with the ID as it's not hitting the jquery at all

Comment: Sure! you should paste the html rendered by razor

Comment: I'm new to this, sorry. Could you please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Using Chrome press ctrl+u on the page and you'll see the source code

Comment: This is what I see: `<div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                t Voice12345
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="NameTextBox" name="Name" type="text" value="1st Credit Voice12345" />
                <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Name" data-valmsg-replace="true" id="NameTexBoxValidator"></span>
            </div>
        </div>`     **Cant see id=Name**

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$("#Name").click(function(){
    if ($("#Name").is(":visible")) {
        $("#NameTextBox").show();
        $("#Name").hide();
    } else { // I'd added this else block for discussion purposes only
        $("#NameTextBox").hide();
        $("#Name").show();
   }
});
```

This will show textbox and hide label on click of the label.
The else part is unreachable though because after the label was hidden, there is no way to trigger this event again (based on given code)

Edit :

```
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { id = "NameTexBoxValidator" })
```

Comment: It doesn't hit the code at all... maybe something to do with the ID ("#Name")??

Comment: inspect element in your browser, maybe id Name is not present.

Comment: maybe conflict with your id's "NameTexBox" was used twice, for validator and textbox

Comment: @YagneshCangi, You need to read and understand the comments I made in the question. You **do not** have an element with `id="Name"`. Your script will **never** be called

Comment: @YagneshCangi please check the id's, stephen is correct